# How to place into an array of addStaff(const Staff&)

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, constructor

I do not understand how to implement the following code to allow the function to write into the existing array.

```
void Project::addStaff(const Staff&)
{
  //add employees into staff array
}
```

having (const Staff&) as parameters is new to me as it does not create an object anyways. I can not change it because it is to be used as is to implement the program correctly. the Staff constructor is as follows

```
Staff::Staff (std::string lname, std::string fname)
  : theLname(lname), theFname(fname)
   {}
```

Is there a way to write the variable for staff so I can access the needed values to place into the array? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Project` class may have a `std::vector` data member, and you can use `vector.push_back()` method to add new `Staff` instances in the array:

```
// Inside Project class:
std::vector<Staff> m_staffPersons;


void Project::addStaff(const Staff& newStaff)
{
    // Add employees into staff array
    m_staffPersons.push_back(newStaff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define `std::vector<Staff>` representing list of employees as a member of this `Project` class:

```
class Project
{
public:
    void addStaff(const Staff&);
    vector<Staff> employees;
}
```

Then your `addStaff` method could look like this:

```
void Project::addStaff(const Staff& newEmployee)
{
    employees.push_back(newEmployee);
}
```

But I would definitely rename class `Staff` since it doesn't say much about itself. `Employee` would be much better name for this class.

Comment: Probably it would be better to make std::vector<Staff> data member private (or protected).

Comment: Maybe. But that's decision that Jake should make.